CreateDialogIndirectParam causes atom leak in MFC application?
I have an MFC Application where I added a common shared non-MFC library routine that displays a dialog with CreateDialogIndirectParam().  However, using deleaker I now see each time it is called, there is an atom leak.  The MFC application is using the latest BCGControlBar Pro
Here's the stack of one where it occurs (they all have in common _AfxCbtFilterHook):
KERNEL32.DLL!GlobalAddAtomW 00007ffa8af62940        
MyApp.exe!_AfxCbtFilterHook Line 618 + 0x7 bytes 00007ff79b707a19   d:\a01\_work\6\s\src\vctools\VC7Libs\Ship\ATLMFC\Src\MFC\wincore.cpp, line 618  
USER32.dll!GetDlgCtrlID + 0x28c bytes 00007ffa89a818ec      
USER32.dll!DefMDIChildProcW + 0x169f bytes 00007ffa89a90a9f     
ntdll.dll!KiUserCallbackDispatcher + 0x1f bytes 00007ffa8b9513df        
win32u.dll!NtUserCreateWindowEx + 0x14 bytes 00007ffa898b1ec4       
USER32.dll!CreateWindowExW + 0x665 bytes 00007ffa89a677b5       
USER32.dll!CreateWindowInBandEx + 0x6cc bytes 00007ffa89a6615c      
USER32.dll!CreateDialogIndirectParamAorW + 0x52 bytes 00007ffa89a63292      
USER32.dll!CreateDialogIndirectParamW + 0x13 bytes 00007ffa89a629a3     
MyApp.exe!CMyClass::CreateMyDialog Line 979 + 0x29 bytes 00007ff79b662635   c:\MyApp\MyApp.CPP, line 979     

The call looks something like:
CreateDialogIndirectParam(GetModuleHandle(NULL), (LPCDLGTEMPLATE) tempbuf, hparentdlg, ::DialogProc, (LPARAM) this);
Any idea on how to stop that?  Is there something I must manually do since the framework is not or does the framework handle the clean up at random times?
TIA!!

This looks like a standard MFC call stack: MFC sets up a local CBT hook so that it can funnel messages that are being sent while CreateWindowExW() is still executing into the user-supplied window class. To do that it needs to associate the C++ class instance with the window and presumably calls SetProp() (which in turn calls GlobalAddAtom()) to do so. If you want to investigate this further you can install the MFC source code so that you can single-step through it.

it call GlobalAddAtom(_afxOldWndProc); ( ie for "AfxOldWndProc423" string). and If the string already exists in the global atom table, the atom for the existing string is returned and the atom's reference count is incremented. so not new data is allocated. also on WM_NCDESTROY - next code executed - GlobalDeleteAtom(GlobalFindAtom(_afxOldWndProc)); so must not me resource leaks here

Is it a false positive with deleaker? I see the same type of report when using SHChangeNotifyRegister()

Probably a false positive. Leak detection tools are inherently bad at tracking resources with shared ownership that are stored in system-private memory. Atoms fall into that category, exacerbated by the fact that the global atom table is shared across all processes.
